# Add prefix to each line of output with sed

Tags: sed

Okay after googling for some minutes it seems this is the regular way to prefix each line of output with `sed`

But I get an error I don't understand.

What does this mean and how can I fix this?

```
$ sed 's/^/#/' test.txt
sed: -e expression #1, char 0: no previous regular expression
```

What my test.txt looks like - it's really just a test

```
### test.txt
a
b
c
d
e
f
g
h
```

Oh yeah.. the version

```
$ sed --version
GNU sed version 4.2.1
Copyright (C) 2009 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE,
to the extent permitted by law.
```

Comment: weired, what's your sed version?

Comment: Works for me. The error would make sense with `s//#/` but not with `s/^/#/`.

Comment: Hmm, I tried with sed 4.2.2 and it worked fine.

Comment: try `sed 's/^\(.\)/#\1/' test.txt` it would do the same but it won't touch the blank lines.

Comment: @AvinashRaj yep, works. Post this as an answer please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code will do the same using capturing group but it won't touch the blank lines.

```
sed 's/^\(.\)/#\1/' test.txt
```

try this if you want to add `#` at the start of a blank line also.

```
sed 's/^\(.\|\)/#\1/' file
```

**Example:**

```
$ cat f
a

b
$ sed 's/^\(.\)/#\1/' f
#a

#b
$ sed 's/^\(.\|\)/#\1/' f
#a
#
#b
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `awk` to solve this too:

```
cat file
a

b
```

To add `#` to all line:

```
awk '{$0="#"$0}1' file
#a
#
#b
```

To add `#` to all non blank line

```
awk 'NF{$0="#"$0}1' file
#a

#b
```